# SSIS transformation Duplicate column Name how to add suffix?

Tags: c#, ssis, transformation, etl, ssis-2012

I am new to SSIS, using Visual Studio 2012 for SSIS package development

The Source data (Flat File) has 2 columns named 'InterestRate' They have the same name, content and are derived in the same way. We will land both fields and distinguish them by adding a sequential numeric suffix to the end of the second column with this name.

I want to have InterestRate & InterestRate1 or InterestRate2...
How do I do that?

Comment: Map them to the desired column names in the destination.

Comment: Before mapping it to the Destination (table), the requirement is to transform the data, if there are any Name repeated (duplicate InterestRate) I should add a sequence number. How do I do that?

Comment: That's a different question.   You should either create a new question or edit your title and question text.

Answer (score 0):

Use Derived Column transformation between Source and Destination.Which ever column name you want to change , you can do that through Derived Column Name.
You can go to Data Flow tab and add Derived Column found under Data Flow Transformations in tool box.